# How to get list of all databases in vertica trough R?

Tags: r, vertica

I am making my connection in R and trying to get list of all databases present in vsql Database. My code is:

```
library(RJDBC)
##connection
conn <- dbConnect(drv, paste0("jdbc:vertica://",client.hostname,":5433/"),
                          user=client.username , password=client.password)
##Query
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT DISTINCT(table_schema) FROM v_catalog.tables;")
```

The above code returns only schema names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT database_name FROM v_catalog.databases;")